# Angular ng-packagr Rollup Build Error

Tags: angular, rollup

I have looked at every issue I can find that has a reference to the error I'm having when trying to package my Angular component library. The error is:

```
BUILD ERROR
Cannot call a namespace ('moment')
Error: Cannot call a namespace ('moment')
... //Rest of stack trace
```

I have tried adding the `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,` attribute to my tsconfig.json file, and the `"target"` is es6. I tried adding a `rollup.config.js` file, and have tried the following ways of importing moment:

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
```

and

```
import moment from 'moment';
```

and

```
import * as momentLib from 'moment';
const moment = momentLib;
```

and

```
import moment from 'moment-es6';
```

None of those worked. But I still get the above error, or that there is no default export for moment.

Does anyone have any tips on how to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

I also tried all the solutions that you also tried, but what worked for me was

```
import moment from 'moment-with-locales-es6';
```

and I added to `dependencies` in `package.json`

```
"moment-with-locales-es6": "latest"
```